# Layout display error when returning from onPause

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I have a layout which includes a GLSurfaceView which takes up the whole screen. At the bottom of the screen, I have a semi-transparent toolbar (LinearLayout) which overlays the GLSurfaceView.
Also, my app is full screen (`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`).

Usually, everything is fine, but starting with ICS, whenever the user comes back to the app (returning from `onPause`), the OS plays a quick animation where the app starts with the Android status bar showing at the top and the app screen pushed down. Then the status bar disappears and the app's screen moves up by that much to get to its normal full screen position.

When this animation completes, the GLSurfaceView ends up overlaying the top half of the toolbar, with the toolbar overlaying the bottom half of the GLSurfaceView. It looks like the part of the toolbar showing at the bottom is exactly the size of the Android status bar.

Of course, I would like the toolbar to completely show and overlay the GLSurfaceView, which is what happens when the app is started all the way from `onCreate`.

Anybody has an idea about what causes this problem and how to fix it?

I found one workaround, but it is far from optimal.
I can get the toolbar to show correctly by posting `invalidate()` to the toolbar some time after `onResume()` is called. But if the `invalidate()` is called too quickly, the problem does not get fixed.
Here is the code for the workaround where `invalidate()` is called 5 seconds after `onResume()`, causing the toolbar to show correctly 5 seconds after the app restarts.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();    

    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();

    // Test to try to fix half hidden toolbar problem
    View toolBar = findViewById(R.id.menu_bar);
    toolBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View toolBar = findViewById(R.id.menu_bar);
            toolBar.invalidate();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

**Edit:**
The above code does not cause the toolbar to show correctly. I took out a line setting text in a debug `TextView` in the code above, and it turns out that the toolbar does not show up if I don't update that totally unrelated `TextView`!

I found another way to make the poor workaround above work by first removing the toolbar when `onResume` is called and bringing it back a while later. See the code below:
Please note that using `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE` will not make the toolbar appear after the delay.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();    

    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();

    // Test to try to fix half hidden toolbar problem
    View toolBar = findViewById(R.id.menu_bar);
    toolBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolBar.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View toolBar = findViewById(R.id.menu_bar);
            toolBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //mDebugText.setText("Menu bar to front.\n" + mDebugText.getText());
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I wish this comment was more help, but... I had this issue also. The only way I found to solve it was to restructure my app to not hide the title bar when the `SurfaceView` was active. Would really love to see a solution to this problem also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more details about this problem and a better workaround, so here is the new info.

First, I discovered that the problem only happened when I was showing ads using Samsung's `AdHubView` class, which is derived from `RelativeLayout`, so the problem might or might not be related to `RelativeLayout`.

This ad view is included in the same top `FrameLayout` which also includes the `GLSurfaceView` and the toolbar (`LinearLayout`). This top `FrameLayout` is not explicitely declared since I used `<merge >` as the top element of my layout.

Now about the better workaround, what I did is hide the `AdHubView` in `onPause` and show it again in `onWindowFocusChanged`. I also tried showing it again in `onResume` but that didn't work in the case where the screen was turned off and I had to unlock the screen to return to the app.

Here are some code samples:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mAdView.setVisibility(AdHubView.GONE);
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(AdHubView.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

With this workaround, I don't need to wait before forcing the toolbar to the top anymore, as I was doing in my previous workaround, so the user never notices anything weird.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is how I worked around this problem. If anyone has a better solution, by all means write it down here and I will choose your answer as the best answer.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    // Delay for the layout request. It must be longer than the time ICS takes to play
    // the animation where the app's screen moves up to fill the space of the Android
    // status bar.
    final int DELAY_MS = 1000; // in ms

    if (hasFocus) {
        // Send a delayed layout request to fix the problem with the toolbar
        // being half hidden after returning from onPause() on some devices 
        // with ICS.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.menu_bar).requestLayout();
            }
        }, DELAY_MS);
    }
}
```

First, I put the code in `onWindowFocusChanged()` because when turning off the screen, `onResume()` is called right after the screen is turned back on (and before the screen is unlocked), so the runnable was being executed before the app was actually shown, and therefore, before the animation was shown, so the problem was still happening in such cases.

Second, I put the delay at 1 second because 500ms was too short. The animation was not done playing and the toolbar still ended up half hidden. Of course this causes the toolbar to be displayed as half hidden for a few ms before it is put back in its rightful position.